# Facebook authorize dialog has no cancel button?

Tags: ios, facebook, legacy

We are using the legacy headers from the Facebook iOS SDK (3.1.1), as we don't want the user to be able to leave the app. This is a particular issue for us, as we are using GameKit and iOS kills the connection rather quickly after leaving the app (a few seconds is enough)

What I am doing right now, to show the login dialog is:

```
m_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:m_fbAppId andDelegate:self];  
NSArray * permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",nil];
[m_facebook authorize:permissions];
```

However the dialog doesn't have a cancel button, so the user has no way of leaving it, except with a successful login. Is there a fix?

Best,
Gorm

Answer (score 0):

If you use an older version of the Facebook SDK, the 'X' button will not appear at the top-left of the authorization dialog. Updating to the latest SDK solved the issue for me.